# Spacing (calculated pixel width) of Text Strings too large on some systems

Tags: c++, string, windows, user-interface, visual-c++

***Problem:***

Our company has some software made in Visual C++ 6.0. I've noticed some inconsistencies when it comes to text spacing in the user interface windows between systems. We are a fairly small company so I don't have a large sample size, but there seems to be two different spacing varieties: the original spacing (how the software was made to look) and a larger, undesired spacing.

***What I've found:***

- Typically, the original spacing can be seen on desktop computers and the undesired spacing on laptops, but this isn't always the case (one coworker's laptop looks like the original spacing).
- We all are running the same version of Windows and have disabled resolution scaling.
- The extra undesired spacing seems to stem from a function to determine the length, in pixels, of a string.
- The undesired spacing is not a fixed amount, but rather, seems to be scaled based on how long the string is; in other words, short strings have only a little extra added spacing while long strings have much more added spacing.
- Using some test strings, I determined that spaces (the character) do not affect the spacing differences. That is, the pixel width differences between the string "this is a test" on two different systems and  the string "thisisatest" on those same two systems are identical. This leads me to believe that this problem might have something to do with the pixel width of each non-space character, almost as if they were treated as being **bold**, or something similar.
- The ratio of the pixel width between two systems of any string without spaces is not cosnsistent; in other words, each character isn't simply 1.2x wider, but this could just be due to rounding based on font size.
- Left-justified text has the extra spacing on the right and vice-versa, while centered text has the extra spacing evenly split on either side.

***Pictures:***

Below is a screenshot of a window on a computer that has the original spacing:
[Spacing, as it was originally designed to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJdEC.png)
Below is a screenshot of the same window (albeit different text in some of the input fields, just ignore) with the undesired spacing:
[Spacing, as it looks on other systems with an undesired look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6p4kC.png)
Below is an image of the two overlapped, with the original spacing on top with ~80% transparency:
[Both of the above, overlapped, to see differences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1L2p.png)

***What I've done:***

As a temporary fix, we simply check the length of a string with a known pixel width and see if they match, and if not, apply a ratio to the pixel width function to attempt to correct for the undesired spacing. Of course, this is not perfect since the issue is more complex that this, and we simply took the average of numerous test strings. Even with this change, there are still problem areas in some of areas of the UI.

***So, the question:***

Is there a root cause to this issue? Is anyone familiar with this issue I describe? I am not a fan of the simple band-aid fix that we have implemented, as I feel that this inconsistency is perhaps tied to a system setting or something that can be easily accounted for. If you would like/need any further information, let me know and I will provide it as soon as I can (if I can).

Comment: There are two types of fonts, fixed pitch (bitmaps) and adjustable width fonts (e.g. scalable) fonts.  The fixed pitch fonts depend on the physical size of the pixel.  Different graphics cards and monitors (screens) can have different pixel widths.  If you want to be neurotic or picking at nits, you should be able to the pixel width information (from the OS) and adjust the fonts as necessary.  You may be able to treat each fixed point bitmap as a matrix and transform them accordingly (or if your lucky, pick the font size that has the best visual representation).

Comment: In embedded systems that use a custom display, font or bitmap sizes are chosen based on the size of the display, the pixel display and the language.  Phrases in some languages may not fit on the display, so a smaller font would need to be used (or a smaller phrase).

Comment: The easiest method would be to have all platforms the same configuration, including monitors and graphic cards.